# Extracting data from Mayavi pipeline -- specifically coordinates for a point-defined-surface

Tags: python, python-3.x, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I am running a script to create a cylindrical surface defined by a set of points. I am using Mayavi to render the visualizations. For the following script, how could I find the coordinates of each point? It seems like Mayavi is doing this behind the scenes in the data pipeline, but I am not too sure how to extract it. Alternatively, I tried doing nested for loops, but I haven't figured out the correct algorithm... I will keep trying in the meantime. However, if someone knows how to extract them from the Mayavi pipeline, that would be great since I won't have to add any more computation time.

```
import numpy as np
import mayavi
from mayavi import mlab

class cylinder:
  def __init__(self, radius, length):
    phi, x = np.mgrid[0:np.pi:50j, 0:length:50j]
    self.z = radius * np.sin(phi)
    self.y = radius * np.cos(phi)
    self.x = x
    self.mesh = mlab.points3d(self.x,self.y,self.z, mode = 'point')


def main():
  cylinder = cylinder(radius=1,length=2)
  mayavi.mlab.axes()
  mlab.show()


main()
```

Comment: `cylinder = cylinder(...)` will lead to an `UnboundLocalError` since `cylinder` is qualified to be a local name due to its appearance on the left-hand side, but it is seen on the right-hand-side before getting assigned. Don't shadow names like that, especially nonlocal ones. Write something like `cyl = cylinder(radius=1, lenth=2)`.

Comment: I've noticed that with more than a year and a half of activity here and 8 questions you haven't accepted any answers on your posts, nor have you given any feedback to answerers bsaed on a cursory glance at a few of those questions. Please consider accepting answers to your older questions, because this signals that your problem is solved and it also gives reputation both to you and the answerer. See also [How does accepting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Okay, thanks I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the data you pass to mayavi will be present in the corresponding data source. I'd note, however, that I wouldn't think that you'd often want to reverse-engineer your data from the pipeline, since it was you who passed those data in the first place (so you should be able to keep track of that data without having to dig down into the low-level vtk machinery).

Anyway, assuming that you only have a single scene and a single data source in your pipeline:

```
engine = mlab.get_engine()
source = engine.scenes[0].children[0]
# choose a scene among engine.scenes if necessary
# choose a source among engine.scenes[0] if necessary

points_data = np.array(source.data.points)
```

In your specific example you passed three arrays of shape `(50,50)` to `points3d`. What we get for `points_data` is an array of shape `(2500,3)`. Suspicious. Sure enough, we can reshape it into the appropriate shape in order to reconstruct the original data:

```
x,y,z = points_data.T
# x,y,z have shape (2500,) now, no way to know the "true" original shape

# if we know what their shape _should_ be, we can fix that too:
x,y,z = points.data.reshape(50,50,3).transpose(2,0,1)

# compare to the original data
radius,length = 1,2
phi, x0 = np.mgrid[0:np.pi:50j, 0:length:50j]
z0 = radius * np.sin(phi)
y0 = radius * np.cos(phi)
print(np.array_equal(x, x0)) # True
print(np.array_equal(y, y0)) # True
print(np.array_equal(z, z0)) # True
```

Since the multidimensional structure of the input arrays is irrelevant to mayavi, I don't expect we can reconstruct the original `x,y,z` arrays with the right *shape* from the pipeline. If I were mayavi I'd `ravel` all the input arrays losing all possible multidimensional structure, and I'm pretty sure that's exactly what happens.

Comment: thank you-- I actually found a way before getting back to this:   `dataset = mayavi.tools.pipeline.get_vtk_src(cylinder.mesh)[0]`  on the next line do 
`datapoints = dataset.points.to_array()`

Comment: @physicsmajor if you have access to `cylinder.mesh` then you have access to `cylinder.x`, `cylinder.y` and `cylinder.z`. What am I missing?

Comment: My goal was to construct a list of coordinates for each point, which would be a list of tuples. Although I had access to `cylinder.x`,`cylinder.y`, and `cylinder.z`, I had trouble constructing the list of unique coordinates since `cylinder.x`/`cylinder.y`/`cylinder.z` are nested arrays. I am sure it can be done using nested for loops, but it's been a while... It also might be more efficient to extract from the pipeline since mayavi has already constructed the data I needed (not as a list of tuples, but as an array of coordinate arrays, which is good enough) so I don't have to write extra code.

Comment: Would you agree?

Comment: @physicsmajor I believe what you're looking for is `zip(cylinder.x.ravel(), cylinder.y.ravel(), cylinder.z.ravel())`. Or this put inside `list()` if you don't just want to iterate over them once.

Comment: Or `np.array([cylinder.x.ravel(), cylinder.y.ravel(), cylinder.z.ravel()]).T` if you're happy with a 2d array.

Comment: It seems like `list(zip(cylinder.x.ravel(), cylinder.y.ravel(), cylinder.z.ravel()))` is exactly what I was looking for-- thank you!

Comment: how come when I try to get the list of coordinates for a cross-section only (that is when length = 0), I get a lot of duplicates?

Comment: @physicsmajor because in that case you're probably using `np.mgrid[0:2*pi*50j, 0:0:50j]`, which along the second variable is similar to `np.linspace(0,0,50)` which contains 50 zeros. If you want a cross-section you don't want a 2d set of data, only a 1d set. Instead of creating a new 2d grid with `length=0` you should be looking at an `x==x0` subset of your 2d grid. So the corresponding points are `inds = x==0; x_section = x[inds]; y_section = y[inds], z_section = z[inds]`, for instance. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes. I also fixed it by doing `phi, x0 = np.mgrid[0:np.pi:50j, 0:length:1j]`, with length = 0, which gives me the same thing

Comment: Hello-- I have a question. How would I be able to change the color of each point? I would like to scan or loop through each (x,y,z) point and pass it to some predetermined function that will check if it satisfies some given condition, if so then it's color must be changed. Is there a way to access the current scalar/color information and change it?

Comment: @physicsmajor changing the colour of an existing plot is probably possible but complicated, and I'd have to look well into it to figure out how. Creating a plot with the right colours on the other hand is very easy, just pass a fourth array as an argument to `points3d` with the same shape as the coordinates, and this will be used to look up colours from the colourmap. You can do stuff like `c = np.where(self.x < self.z, 0, 1)` to create a binary array which would give you two colours in the plot: one where the array `c` is `0` and the other where it's `1`.